# Как преобразовать список в список строк

Tags: python

У нас есть информация в таком виде: `[1]`. Нам необходимо из нее получить `['1']`. Вопрос: как это сделать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для преобразования элемента в строку используется такая конструкция: `str(your_var)`

```py
my_list = [1,2,3,4]
# Вариант 1
my_str_list_1 = [str(x) for x in my_list]
print("List1: "+str(my_str_list_1))
# List1: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
# Вариант 2
my_str_list_2 = list()
for val in my_list:
  my_str_list_2.append(str(val)) # преобразуем элемент массива в строку
print("List2: "+str(my_str_list_2));
# List2: ['1', '2', '3', '4']
```

Answer (score 2):

Например, применить функцию `str` ко всем элементам списка:

```py
print(list(map(str, [1, 2, 3])))
```

Вывод:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Список **чисел** в список **строк** можно преобразовать так:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]

lst = [str(item) for item in lst]

print(lst)
```

Или так:

```py
lst = [1, 2, 3]

for index, item in enumerate(lst):
    lst[index] = str(item)

print(lst)
```

Вывод в обеих случаях:

```
['1', '2', '3']
```